# Fields as a reflective subcategory of integral domains?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

A subcategory $\mathbf A$ is [reflective subcategory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory) of $\mathbf B$ if for every $B\in\mathbf B$  there exists an $A_B\in\mathbf A$ and a  $\mathbf B$-morphism $r_B \colon B \to A_B$ such that: for any $A\in\mathbf A$ and any $\mathbf B$-morphism $f \colon B \to A$  there exists unique $\mathbf A$-morphism $\overline f \colon A_B \to A$ such that $\overline f\circ r_B=f$.

[image: Diagram - reflection]

This is equivalent to saying that the inclusion functor $E \colon \mathbf A \to \mathbf B$ has a left adjoint.

[Current revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Reflective_subcategory&oldid=491834125) of the Wikipedia article on reflective subcategories claims that

> The category of fields is a reflective subcategory of the category of integral domains. The reflector is the functor which sends each integral domain to its field of fractions.

I don't think this is true - an easy counterexample is the homomorphism $f \colon \mathbb Z \to\mathbb Z_2$ given by $f(n)=n\mod 2$. This homorphism obviously cannot be extended to $\overline f \colon \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z_2$.

The above claim would be true if we considered the categories of integral domains only with injective ring homomorhpisms.

Am I correct? Did I miss something there?

The same problem has already been mentioned on the [talk page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Reflective_subcategory) of this Wikipedia article, so this is more-or-less just a sanity check.

Comment: The article [field of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) states explicitly what the category of integral domains has to be here.

Comment: Small typo in definition of $r_B$: domain should be $B$, not $A$.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMeyers. Corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct... and the category of integral domains *is* defined to only have the injective homomorphisms as arrows. Unfortunately, this part of the definition sometimes seems to be left out when the category is introduced....